# FeathersJS: Creating a record inside a hook

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I am new to FeathersJS and I am trying to do the following:

My app has two entities named `Company` and `User`. When someone registers a new company the name, email and a password for the owner are informed.

Then, after creating the record for the company in my companies table I need:

1) To retrieve the `id` of the new company;

2) Create an user with this `id` ad  `companyId`, the name of the owner, the email of the owner and the given password.

Of course this should be done in a `after insert hook` for the companies service, but I am very confused about how to invoke the users service to perform this insert.

This is my **companies.model.js** file:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const companies = sequelizeClient.define('companies', {
    company: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 100
    },
    cpfcnpj: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 25
    },
    owner: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 100
    },
    cpf: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 25
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 100
    },
    addr1: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 100
    },
    addr2: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 100
    },
    city: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 100
    },
    state: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 2
    },
    zip: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 10
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 50
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  companies.associate = function (models) {

  };

  return companies;
};
```

and this is my **users.model.js**:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const users = sequelizeClient.define('users', {
    companyID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull false,
      size: 11
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      size: 100
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      size: 100
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      default: 'CL',
      size: 2
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  users.associate = function (models) {

  };

  return users;
};
```

I understand that in my file **companies.hooks.js** I should have something like

```
module.exports = {

  before: {
    all: [],
    ...
  },

  after: {
    ...
    create: [ insertUser() ],
    ...
  },

  error: {
    ...
  }
};
```

but apart from that I don't really know how should I write my `insertUser()` function or where to put it. As I told you, I'm new with FeathersJS, this is my first day.

## EDITED:

The first part of the question is answered. I used some `console.log()`s here and there and found out the object `context` passed to the hook has an object named `result` inside it when you are in an `after` hook, which is the case. Using this object now have the company id, the name and email of the owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all inside `context`.

When you use a `hook` in FeatherJS, your `hook function` receives an object named `context` and this object has all you need.

In an `after hook` we have `context.result`, an object with the result of the previous query. In an insert query, like in the question, `context.result` has all the inserted information, including the id of the inserted company.

Besides, the `context` object contains a reference to the FeathersJS `app` object, which is the application being run, with all its services and hooks and everything. So, in order create the user, as required in the question, all you have to do is:

Edit the file **src/services/companies/companies.hooks.js** and add, right in the beginning, after the imports, a function like this

```
const createUser = function(context) {
  const userRecord = {
    companyID: context.result.id,
    name: context.result.owner,
    email: context.result.email,
    // Get all other information you need here
  };
  context.app.service('users').create(userRecord);
};
```

Register this hook right below in the same file

```
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [authenticate('jwt')],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [ createUser ], // <<=== registering the hook
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

And it is done! Every time you create a new company the `after hook` will be executed and a new user will be created in association with that company.

Click [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) for more information on FeathersJS hooks.